# EACCES Issue on npm fresh install on WSL Debian trying to update to the latest version

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello everyone i started with a fresh wsl distrib of Debian and installed nodejs and npm on it.

When trying to update to the latest release of npm with the following command:

> sudo npm install npm@latest -g

I get some weird issues who seems pretty common on wsl from what i saw on my internet researchs the only answer who seems to works but not really resolving properly the issue is setting the unsafe permissions to true with the following command:

> npm config set unsafe-perm true

I would avoid to use this method and find an more clean way to resolve the issue.

Here is the console output:

```
####@#####:~$ sudo npm install npm@latest -g
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap- 
ansi
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap-ansi' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap-ansi' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap-ansi' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm- 
18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap-ansi',
npm ERR!      dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap-ansi' -> 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/npm-18aca6f9/node_modules/wrap- 
ansi',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging/wrap-ansi-9f8997e7' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as 
the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double- 
check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try 
running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not 
recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-15T23_53_32_851Z-debug.log
```

I followed the doc of the nodejs website for installation using curl in root mode to get the repository of the last 11.x version of node.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm suck on this as well in my WSL, all global installs suddenly fail. Settings `npm config set unsafe-perm true` didn't work for me.

Comment: Hello,  well actually i'm facing the issue only on the global installing of the npm package for others global install i don't have any problem maybe watch out for setting an npm-global directory in your home folder maybe this link from the npm doc could help you aswell: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Thank you. I tried that the other day, with no luck. Switched to `yarn`, it works so I won't complain. Sometimes you just break npm and you have no idea why, lol.

Answer (score 4):

Experiencing this issue on WSL Ubuntu distro, and only on `rename`.

Happens also on `npm update` even after using `chown` on my node_modules directory.

The workaround that I got working is to simply avoid `update` and use `install` instead (npm install npm@x is technically an update too). I know this is very bothersome but aside from this I'm not sure how to make it work. Commands that *rename* directories trigger this but not on `create` or `delete`.

Comment: This hasn't been working for me since some projects have postinstall actions that will use `rename` ...

Comment: @charlybones maybe try upgrading to WSL 2, apparently there's better file IO management on there. I haven't given a chance myself as I went back to mac after this.